# Trigger a function when specific frame number is reached - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I wanted friends, do the following when my MC get a determanido internal quandro, it triggers a function to another MC. for example when the ball hit the wall, a person goes to search - la, I have tried using :

`("root") {root.MC.play ()}`

**Translation from comments:** 
Friends, I have an **MC_1** with 10 frames, when it reaches frame 5, I want another movieClip **MC_2** to respond (eg: to move or fade etc)

Comment: More generates a lot of errors, not longer works as it should

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Amigo eu tenho MC_1 com 10 quadros quando o quadro vêm em 5 quiser que o movimento MC_2... Portugues-Brazil: Amigo eu tenho MC_1 com 10 frames, quando o frame chegar no 5 quero que o MC_2 se mova

Comment: Its messy @Batman, I suspect he is using frame numbers for "states" of the game or such but after that its all confusing... Too much missing information and meaningless "test my code" sample

Comment: @LailsonRsilva, Please show the code for: How are you making **MC_1** got to other frames? That is where you also check if the number is now 5 and then use `If/else` to tell **MC_2** to do something...

Answer (score 0):

creating a **ENTER_FRAME** listener for your MC_1 is the easiest way to achieve this

```
MC_1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,respond);

function respond(e:Event):void{
    if(MC_1.currentFrame>=5)
        MC_2.gotoAndPlay(2);
        //or any other respose you want from MC_2 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**addFrameScript** can be used in AS3 to specify a function to execute on reaching a MovieClip frame.

```
MovieClip.addFrameScript(index:int, func:Function);
```

A sample implementation of this:

```
// addFrameScript's index is zero Based, hence 4 means frame 5
MC_1.addFrameScript(4, funcToExecute);

function funcToExecute():void{
    // this will get called when MC_1 reaches frame 5
    // do stuff here, like manipulating MC_2, etc...
}
```